# Click on radio button and display the corresponding value inside the radio button as selected in react js material UI design

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new to react js material UI design.
What I want is something like below.

[image]

If I clicked the first radio button , its value 1 should be displayed inside the selected radio button.

I could only implement the standalone radio button using the following.

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { green } from '@material-ui/core/colors';
import Radio from '@material-ui/core/Radio';

const GreenRadio = withStyles({
 root: {
  color: green[400],
  '&$checked': {
  color: green[600],
  },
},
checked: {},
})((props) => <Radio color="default" {...props} />);

export default function RadioButtons() {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = React.useState('a');

  const handleChange = (event) => {
   setSelectedValue(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
   <div>
    <Radio
    checked={selectedValue === 'a'}
    onChange={handleChange}
    value="a"
    name="radio-button-demo"
    inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'A' }}
  />
  <Radio
    checked={selectedValue === 'b'}
    onChange={handleChange}
    value="b"
    name="radio-button-demo"
    inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'B' }}
  />
  <GreenRadio
    checked={selectedValue === 'c'}
    onChange={handleChange}
    value="c"
    name="radio-button-demo"
    inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'C' }}
  />
  <Radio
    checked={selectedValue === 'd'}
    onChange={handleChange}
    value="d"
    color="default"
    name="radio-button-demo"
    inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'D' }}
  />
  <Radio
    checked={selectedValue === 'e'}
    onChange={handleChange}
    value="e"
    color="default"
    name="radio-button-demo"
    inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'E' }}
    size="small"
  />
</div>
);
}
```

How can I get the value inside the selected button?

Comment: I don't think that it's possible because the `Radio` component uses input type="radio" HTML native element. For what you want you need to create a component that acts like a radio but renders custom elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with: I built a custom component from ButtonBase.
It works fine but is less clever than @Gh05d. On the other hand it avoids writing global style or digging into Material-UI's internals:
[image: Edit youthful-sound-fuwhb]

```
const useStyle = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    margin: 4,
    borderRadius: "50%"
  },
  checked: {
    height: 30,
    width: 30,
    backgroundColor: "#0a2",
    color: "#fff",
    borderRadius: "50%",
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  notchecked: {
    height: 26,
    width: 26,
    borderRadius: "50%",
    border: "2px solid #00000066",
    color: "#ffffff00"
  }
}));

function MyButton(props) {
  const { children, checked, ...rest } = props;

  const classes = useStyle();

  return (
    <ButtonBase {...rest} className={classes.root}>
      <div className={clsx(checked ? classes.checked : classes.notchecked)}>
        {children}
      </div>
    </ButtonBase>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = React.useState("a");

  const handleChange = (letter) => (event) => {
    setSelectedValue(letter);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <MyButton
        checked={selectedValue === "a"}
        onClick={handleChange("a")}
        value="a"
      >
        A
      </MyButton>
      <MyButton
        checked={selectedValue === "b"}
        onClick={handleChange("b")}
        value="b"
      >
        B
      </MyButton>
      <MyButton
        checked={selectedValue === "c"}
        onClick={handleChange("c")}
        value="c"
      >
        C
      </MyButton>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Many ways lead to Rome ;-)

Answer (score 4):

It is a bit of a hack but a combination of *(s)css* and custom [data elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) does the trick. First, I added a custom attribute with the value of the field to it (`data-test`, you will obviously have a better idea for a name than me):

```
  <Radio
    checked={selectedValue === "e"}
    onChange={handleChange}
    value="e"
    data-test="e"
    color="default"
    name="radio-button-demo"
    inputProps={{ "aria-label": "E" }}
    size="small"
  />
```

Then I used this *scss*:

```
.Mui-checked {
  position: relative;

  .MuiSvgIcon-root + .MuiSvgIcon-root {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  &::after {
    content: attr(data-test);
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
  }
}
```

`Mui-checked` is the class *MaterialUI* gives the element when it is checked. As this is a `span`, it can have pseudo elements. So basically I am accessing the custom data element and setting the `content` property to it's value. `.MuiSvgIcon-root.PrivateRadioButtonIcon-layer-6` is the selector to get the default dot in the middle of the `checkbox`. This gets hidden.

You would have to play around with the styles a bit to fit your use case and you can find a demo [here](https://codepen.io/Gh05d/pen/bGpzgpv).

**EDIT**:
Here is the *css*, I also updated the selector to improve it's stability:

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.Mui-checked {
  position: relative;
}

.Mui-checked::after {
  content: attr(data-test);
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
}

.MuiSvgIcon-root + .MuiSvgIcon-root {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: how can I implement the css inside material UI design? Can you just check this, https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-dream-qj551?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: I added the css to my answer. Your problem was that you added scss to a css file. This is now pure css which you can copy there.

Comment: But if I try to paste this css inside App.tsx file itself, following the material ui pattern, it shows attr is not defined . https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-dream-qj551?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Did you add the `data-test` property to the Radio Component?

Comment: yes I've added that. You can see that in the link I provided

Comment: It does not work because you pass it as a variable, not as a string. Do this instead: `"attr(data-test)`" and you should be fine. Also, your style solution does not understand the sibling selector, so move `.MuiSvgIcon-root + .MuiSvgIcon-root {
  opacity: 0;
}` back into the *styles.css*.